# What is the running procedure of this Fibonacci program with memoization (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, memoization

This is a valid JavaScript program to generate the Fibonacci number, implemented with memoization.

```
function memoize(fn) {
    cache = {};
    return function(...args){
        if (cache[args]) {
            return cache[args];
        }
        const results = fn.apply(null, args);
        cache[args] = results;
        return results;
    }
}

function slowfib(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

fib = memoize(slowfib);

module.exports = fib;
```

After using debugger statements, I realize that `memoize` is called only once, even though `fib` is called multiple times.

Why is this so? More specifically, how does `fib = memoize(slowfib)` work?

Answer (score 0):

Just like with `a = myFunction(b)`, `fib = memoize(slowfib)` is simply only executed once. The result of it is a new function, which is stored in `fib`, and which is used whenever `fib(x)` is executed. So, your debugger should show that the following *is* executed for every invocation:

```js
function(...args){
    if (cache[args]) {
        return cache[args];
    }
    const results = fn.apply(null, args);
    cache[args] = results;
    return results;
}
```